# Cannot log global variable in Angular 5?

Tags: angular

Using Angular 5, I am trying to fire a web request, and store the items in a global variable to be used later in the template.

The variable logs correctly in the function it is created in but other attempts to log result in undefined.

Here is the .ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  testitems;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient){
    console.log(this.testitems) //logs undefined
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      // Make the HTTP request:
      var test = this.http.get("https://example.com/dev/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Document Separator Barcodes')/items?$orderBy=ID").subscribe(data => {
        // Read the result field from the JSON response.
        console.log("data", data);
        console.log("data.value", data['value']);
        this.testitems = data['value']; //logs here
    });
  }

}
```

I don't understand why this isn't working as I declared my variable in my class. What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: This is because `ngOnInit` runs *after* the `constructor`.

Answer (score 2):

**`ngOnInit`** is part of Angular **`lifecycle`** and **`constructor`** is part of **`ES6`** class.

Manily we use constructor to do the Dependency Injection of services.

In this case you are getting the values on **`ngOnInit`** which is executed after the constructor is called. So your data will be undefined, even though you declared it globally.

Comment: Is the better practice to fire web requests in the constructor or ngOnInit?

Comment: its always to place it inside ngOninit

Comment: if you need the data to be present in the page load use a shared service